Getting broken image in the Extent Report by using Selenium TestNg in IntelliJ IDE
When I run the below code in IntelliJ IDE, the image is not displaying in the extent report but the same image is showing in the project folder.
I tried different ways but got the same issue. same is working fine in eclipse
    
        File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);//temp directory
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/screenshot/" + methodName + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()
                + ".png";

        File destination = new File(path);

        try {
            FileHandler.copy(srcFile, destination);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return path;

    }

public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println((result.getMethod().getMethodName() + " failed!"));
        String methodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();
        test.get().fail("Test failed");
        try {
            test.get().fail(result.getThrowable(), MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(captureScreenshot(methodName),methodName).build());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        test.get().getModel().setEndTime(getTime(result.getEndMillis()));
    }

